# Retrieve fields, such as First Name, Last Name from the DocuSign Document through C# code

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Retrieve fields, such as First Name, Last Name from the DocuSign Document through C# code

I tried with fetching fields with passing template id of my document

```
var apiClient = new ApiClient("https://na3.docusign.net/​");
TemplatesApi envelopesApi2 = new TemplatesApi();
CustomFields cfe = envelopesApi2.ListCustomFields(apiAccountId, templateid);
```

I want to retrieve First name and Last name form the signed document

Answer (score 0):

Chetna, you were using the TemplateAPI but a "signed document" can only be a for n envelope. A template is a "blue print" for envelopes which, after they are signed by all parties, allow for a "signed document".
The information you want is in the Tabs of the document, and these are associated with a specific Recipient. Please see https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/tabs for information about our tabs API.